# How would you say "Is any of that good" or "Is any of the [noun] [adjective]" in French?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, formulation-idiomatique, déterminants

How would you say something like "Is any of that good" or "Is any of this food good" in French? Would you say:

- Est-ce que quelque chose de ça est bon ?
- Est-ce que l'un de ça est bon ?
- Est-ce que tout de ça est bon ?
- Est-ce que quelque chose de cette nourriture est bon ?
- Est-ce que l'un de cette nourriture est bon ?
- Est-ce que tout de cette nourriture est bon ?

or are none of these correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways you can say it as long as you use idiomatic *il y a*.

> Y a-t-il quelque chose de bon dans tout ça ? / Est-ce qu'il y a quelque chose de bon dans tout ça ?

Rather than *nourriture* use *à manger*

> Y a-t-il quelque chose de bon à manger dans tout ça ? / Est-ce qu'il y a quelque chose de bon à manger dans tout ça ? Y a-t-il quelque chose de bon à manger là-dedans ?

For an open question you'd still use *il y a* :

> Qu'y a-t-il de bon à manger là-dedans ?

Note that *là-dedans* would be used even if food is laid out on the table (as opposed to being inside a cupboard.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !